# Configuring Apache HttpClientBuilder to have timeout and cookies

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I used the code from [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-cookies) to send cookies in my HttpClient request, and the code from [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout) to set timeouts for the same HttpClient. Problem is setting the cookie store is done when the HttpClient is built from the HttpClientBuilder...

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
```

But setting the RequestConfig with the timeouts also seems to happen at the same place....

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
```

So how can I create an HttpClient while doing both (setting a cookie stores and request config with timeouts)?

Answer (score 1):

HttpClientBuilder is what is known as a 'fluent interface' so each of those configuration methods returns the builder back to you and you can chain calls.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
  .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
  .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
  .build();
```